# Looking for file 0.3.19

Tags: bitcoin-core

I am looking for this update to the Bitcoin core that Satoshi Nakamoto attached to his final message on 12.13.2010. [image: screenshot]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I did some searching:

- [archive.org...sf/projects](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/files/Bitcoin/bitcoin-0.3.19/*)
  -> unfortunately these are all redirects.
- [archive.org...downloads.sf](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/bitcoin/Bitcoin/bitcoin-0.3.19/*)
  -> unfortunately these were captured much too recently, when the files had already disappeared on sf.net

I assume you already found the [git tag](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/v0.3.19), that way you can build it your self. But I think you mean to get the actual binary built by Satoshi?

You could also try linux distributions, like [debian](https://tracker.debian.org/news/433532/accepted-bitcoin-0319dfsg-6-source-amd64/), but I think they have build this themselves from source.

UPDATE: I found the linux version here: https://bitcoin.ninja/ancient-bitcoind/